# thinkpad 10 running 14.10 2 external monitors not recognized

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, 14.10, thinkpad

I am using a Thinkpad 10 tablet, model number: TP00064AFX, running ubuntu 14.10. I would like to extend the screen to 2 23" asus monitors. They displayed upon plugin on windows 8.1 however when I tried using them on ubuntu neither showed. I checked xrandr and they were not recognized. Also, I checked if there were any drivers to install and none were listed. This is a huge disappointment as I mainly use ubuntu.

Furthermore, I tried plugging into the thinkpad tablet 2 docking station and using the hdmi and there still was no connection to the monitors. Then, I tried plugging in the thinkpad usb 3.0 hub and still nothing. However, when plugged into the 3.0 hub audio, mouse, keyboard, external hdd, and ethernet were recognized. This hub uses display port video connections and i am aware that ubuntu does not currently support display port video out; however, i heard that 15.04 will be supporting this. Either way my tablet, with or without the hub is not displaying external monitors. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: I'm having the sam eproblem with my Lenovo T530 and two dell monitors attached via the dockingstations two outputs. X.org is only using one external monitor plus th ebuild in, the other one is black. Only in text mode I see the same image on all 3 screens, but that isn't satisfying ;-)